# Hiding a field title label of a field collections field?

Tags: entities

I have created several fields using the [field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module, but I cannot hide one of the field labels (within a collection). I've tried it in the UI and I've tried hiding it programmatically with `hook_form_alter`, but it continues to be displayed.

Is their a 'trick' to hiding the field labels created by this module? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Im using field collection right now, and as a quick test I have gone to Structure > Field COllections, then manage display, and I am able to select 'hidden' from the label column and hide all labels. What field are you trying to hide a label for?

Comment: Check out this simplytest.me site: http://s90fe10aa72ce1a6.s3.simplytest.me/node#overlay=admin/structure/field-collections/field-test/display (u: admin p: admin) and see if you can hide the 'Example' label. Thanks.

Comment: It still displays at: http://s90fe10aa72ce1a6.s3.simplytest.me/node#overlay=node/add/page, no?

Comment: Ah, are you trying to hide it from the admin pages?

Comment: http://s90fe10aa72ce1a6.s3.simplytest.me/test is an example with "Example" label hidden

Comment: My 30mins ran out on the site. Here's a new link. I want to hide the label 'Example' in 'TEST': http://sef5878073f425de.s3.simplytest.me/node#overlay=node/add/page. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the admin says it's hidden, but it's not: http://sef5878073f425de.s3.simplytest.me/node#overlay=admin/structure/field-collections/field-test/display.

Comment: That's the admin side label. All default options built into field UI are set to hide labels for the published node. To hide the admin side label, you can either re-name the field to something better, use CSS in a sub theme of your admin theme to hide it, or use hook_form_alter in your admin sub themes template folder to render the field with no label.

Comment: Doesn't hide labels on the page either, and `hook_form_alter` does not hide it either.

Comment: Look at this page where I have added 5 values into that field collection. On the rendered node, all "example" labels are hidden. http://sef5878073f425de.s3.simplytest.me/test

Comment: Sorry, the 30mins rans out. Can you quickly create again here, so I can see what you did: http://se51af703797a9ad.s3.simplytest.me/. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After our discussion, these are the steps to clear the labels from a published node field collection field.

1. Head to Structure > Field Collections > Manage Display (For your collection) 
   Under the label column, make sure all select boxes are set to "Hidden".
2. Next, head to Structure > Content Types > Your Content Type > Manage Display (For your collection)
   Same as before, Under the label column, make sure all select boxes are set to "Hidden".

This wont hide the labels in the admin node/add/yourcontenttype page, but when you save the node, and look at the published page, the labels will be gone.

To remove the edit, delete and add links, Structure > Content Types > Your Content Type > Manage Display and click the settings icon on your field collection field. Then simply delete the edit, delete and add text from the text fields. Click update. Then save the content type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand what you are saying, but, unfortunately, it is the labels in the (admin) form that I need to hide. I see what I was trying will only hide the labels in the displayed node.

Comment: OK, in that case, just grab the class of the containing div, and use a simple display:none; in CSS for that label. You will need to either add this in your admin themes CSS (which would get wiped in an update), or create a quick sub theme for your admin theme.

Comment: Yea, it looks like that may be my only option. Always a last resort, but still it does the job.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would do, especially to save time. Unless the client is paying by the hour! :-P

Answer (score 1):

Inside `hook_form_alter` make `#title_display = 'invisible'.`

```
$form['your_field_name']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
```

Comment: #title_display not works for field_collection items